# Script executes before progress-bar starts

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

I have an issue where my progress-bar starts after the rest of the code completes. Now I know whats wrong, but i cant sort of find a way to do the next step.

I realize that whats happening is asynchronous and I need to use a promise. Can you look at my code and give some hints why?

```
    var count=1;
    var SIZE =100
    function test() {
        if (count < SIZE) {
            var value = Math.round((count / SIZE) * 100);
            count++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', value + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', value);
                test();
            }, 100);
        }
        return;
    };

    test().then($('body').css('background-color', '#76870b'));
```

I would like the test() to run, then have the other code execute.

Comment: you want the test function to be promise?

Comment: I updated the original code - I forgot to add the counter in (count++).

Answer (score 1):

You can call a second function at the end of the first in this case.

```js
var count = 1;
var SIZE = 100

function test() {
  if (count < SIZE) {
    var value = Math.round((count / SIZE) * 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.progress-bar').css('width', value + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', value);

    }, 100);
  }
  console.log('Im Executed');
  secondFunction(); // call second function
  return;
};

function secondFunction() {
  $('body').css('background-color', '#76870b')
}

test();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Or:**

```
test();
secondFunction();
```

It will run `test()` first then `secondFunction()`.

Comment: This didn't work Mr. x (Is that a name taken from the song by Ultravox?).The progress bar stopped working.

Comment: @ChipAhoy It should work, let me check again. *No, actually it taken from Resident Evil Games, but i used due Mr Unknown*

Comment: I added the missing "count++" to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 1;
var SIZE = 100

var test = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (count < SIZE) {
    var value = Math.round((count / SIZE) * 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('sdfsdfsdf');
      $('.progress-bar').css('width', value + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', value);
      resolve({
        'heloo': 'dsfsdf'
      });
    }, 100);
  } else {
    reject('fdsfsd');
  }
});


test().then((resp) => {
  console.log('hello', resp);
  $('body').css('background-color', '#76870b')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was what I was expecting to see Zabusa. I want the test() function to run - which is the progress bar loop. When its finished, THEN do the other code.